# why does calling scrollToPosition creates a row behind the list?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

In my recyclerview I have a swipe to delete as well as undo action.
Whenever I undo the delete action I made, a row behind the list appears.

Here is the current setup of my app:

```
Activity
 - Fragment
   - Recyclerview
```

Here is my delete action. This is inside the recyclerview adapter:

```
cards.remove(pos);
notifyItemRemoved(pos);
```

And here is my undo action:

```
#inside my fragment
adapter.undoDiscard(pos, card);
layoutManager.scrollToPosition(pos);

#inside my adapter
public void undoDiscard(int pos, Card card) {
    cards.add(pos, card);
    notifyItemInserted(pos);
}
```

Here's my observations so far:

1. When the recyclerview is created from an `Activity`, the bug doesn't appear
2. When I turn off the animation of the recyclerview, the bug doesn't happen
3. The bug seems to come from `scrollToPosition`
4. The bug doesn't happen when I use `notifyDataSetChanged`

To illustrate the problem, here is a sample image.
[image]

After calling undo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The bug is caused by the animation of recyclerview. Thus, the solution is to turn off the animation temporarily while calling `scrollToPosition`. In my case I'm using a `snackbar` to give the user the option to undo the changes. So I'm bringing back the animation after dismissing the snackbar.

```
snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
            super.onDismissed(snackbar, event);
            recyclerview.setItemAnimator(animator);
    })
```